# Undefined reference c++, unusual case

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, compiler-errors, g++

I'm creating a queue class in c++ and am having trouble compiling with a makefile. My queue.cpp class is here

```
#include "queue.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

queue::queue()
{
   front_p = NULL;
   back_p = NULL;
   current_size = 0;
}

void queue::enqueue(int item)
{
    node newnode = node(item, NULL);
   if (front_p == NULL) //queue is empty
    {
       front_p = &newnode;
       back_p = &newnode;
    }
   else 
   {
       back_p->next = &newnode;
       back_p = &newnode;
   }
   current_size ++;
}
```

My header file (queue.h) is here

```
class queue
{
  public:
    queue(); // constructor - constructs a new empty queue.
    void enqueue( int item ); // enqueues item.
    int dequeue();  // dequeues the front item.
    int front();   // returns the front item without dequeuing it.
    bool empty();  // true iff the queue contains no items.
    int size();  // the current number of items in the queue.
    int remove(int item); // removes all occurrances of item 
      // from the queue, returning the number removed.

  private:
    class node  // node type for the linked list 
    {
       public:
           node(int new_data, node * next_node ){
              data = new_data ;
              next = next_node ;
           }
           int data ;
           node * next ;
    };

    node* front_p ;
    node* back_p ;
    int current_size ; // current number of elements in the queue.
};
```

test program (tester.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "queue.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    cout << "Lalalalala" << endl;
    queue q1;
    q1.enqueue(5);
}
```

makefile

```
all: tester

tester: queue.o
    g++ -o tester tester.cpp

queue.o: queue.cpp queue.h
    g++ -c queue.cpp

clean:
    rm -f tester *.o
```

when I type "make" or "make all" I get this error:

```
g++ -o tester tester.cpp
/tmp/ccTOKLWU.o: In function `main':
tester.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `queue::queue()'
tester.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `queue::enqueue(int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tester] Error 1
```

The unusual thing about it, is that when compiled in visual studio on a windows machine, there are no errors. I haven't the faintest idea why it shouldn't compile on a linux machine in the way I am doing so. Would anyone kindly explain?

Answer (score 8):

Your makefile is incorrect - it compiles `tester.cpp` with a dependency on `queue.o`, but it does not link `queue.o` at all. That is why the compilation of `tester.cpp` results in an unresolved reference.

You should change your make file as follows:

```
all: tester

tester: queue.o tester.o
    g++ queue.o tester.o -o tester

tester.o: tester.cpp tester.h
    g++ -c tester.cpp

queue.o: queue.cpp queue.h
    g++ -c queue.cpp

clean:
    rm -f tester *.o
```

Comment: son of a........
thank you my friend, this was bugging me!! I'm still not entirely familiar with the makefile concept.